# DICOM slice corrupted when saved as PNG

Tags: c#, itk, simpleitk

I'm using SimpleITK to read a DICOM, and save a particular slice as a PNG file. I can write back a new DICOM file to disk fine, and it looks as expected. But whenever I try to save it in any other format, it's greatly corrupted. By that I mean it looks nothing like the input, it's completely garbled.

Here is the code:

```
        var imageReader = new ImageFileReader();
        imageReader.SetOutputPixelType(PixelIDValueEnum.sitkUInt8);
        var dicomFileNames = ImageSeriesReader.GetGDCMSeriesFileNames(@"D:\Study");
        imageReader.SetFileName(dicomFileNames[255]);
        var image = imageReader.Execute();
        var fileWriter = new ImageFileWriter();
        fileWriter.SetFileName("slice.png");
        fileWriter.Execute(image);
```

Getting the image's buffer and using it to create a BitMap suffers the same problem. Reading the DICOM series (my eventual goal) instead of one file, and using the 3D volume and extracting a slice in that manner also has the same issue.

What am I missing?

EDIT: Using `PixelIDValueEnum.sitkUInt16` greatly improves the output of `ImageFileWriter`, although the contrast is off and loses some detail. I still cannot convert the buffer to a BitMap and save that as a PNG, this code still creates corrupted data:

```
        var size = image.GetSize();
        var length = (int)(size[0] * size[1]) * 2;
        var buffer = image.GetBufferAsUInt16();

        var rgbValues = new byte[length];

        Marshal.Copy(buffer, rgbValues, 0, length);

        var newBitmap = new Bitmap((int)image.GetWidth(), (int)image.GetHeight(), (int)image.GetWidth(), PixelFormat.Format16bppArgb1555, buffer);
        newBitmap.Save(@"C:\test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

I have tried every `PixelFormat.16bpp*` value without success, some data must be getting lost, because the output of the ImageFileWriter is more than 50% larger than when I save the bitmap.

Here is the bad BitMap:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most medical images are 16 bit deep (`short` or `unsigned short`), not 8 bit (`sitkUInt8`). Try a few other pixel formats. If that does not help, attach an extracted PNG slice - that will allow more/better advice.

Comment: Thank you, `sitkUint16` does greatly improve the output of the `ImageFileWriter`,  although it is inverted and loses some detail. I still cannot get the BitMap to work, and have posted more code and the image itself.

Comment: Have you tried other pixel types besides UInt16? How about `sitkInt16`, `sitkInt32`, `sitkUInt32`, `sitkVectorUInt8` (8-bit RGB)? Have you looked at relevant DICOM tags, such as `[0028,0100] BitsAllocated`? Can you share the input DICOM image?

Comment: Bits allocated and bits used are both 16. ushort gives the best results with the sitk ImageFileWriter, I think it doesn't apply the slope and VOI LUT calculations. If I did those it would probably be correct. There's definitely a data type or pixel format problem when I try to create the BitMap in C#. I'm able to get perfect output from Python with a uint16 numpy array. I probably need to experiment more with it in C#.

Comment: Have you tried `Format16bppGrayScale` instead of `Format16bppArgb1555`?

Comment: I tried all of the 16bit pixel formats. I think there's a data type conversion issue that is scrambling all of the pixels prior to creating the `BitMap`.

Comment: Maybe the buffer is already RGB? Try `Format48bppRgb` and `Format24bppRgb`.